# upgrade to Gurrido grid 5.5.5 not working

Tags: jqgrid

I am have been working in free jqGrid 4.15 and now migrating to Gurrido 5.5.5.

I am using spring 5.X MVC with JSP as view.

I am getting following exceptions.

> Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decimalSeparator')
> URL: https://localhost:9443/EVC/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
> Line Number: 472

But on some pages its working fine.

Comment: This type of description does not help us to resolve the problem. Mostly this is caused due the fact that you have not replaced all the files. When upgrade, please be a sure you replace the language file and css file with the guriddo ones

Comment: css files have also been replaced.but the problem persist.kindly let me know details needed

Comment: one part of page is working fine. Following are versions being used .  Jquery ui - 1.12 , jquery - 3.1.0 and i am using an third party  multi select library

Comment: its showing error in this function of jqgrid code NumberFormat:function(e,t) .   Browser firefox - 92.01.1

Comment: do you have replace the language file too - by example **grid.loacale-en.js**, which is important too.

Comment: Another reson for this can be that your free jqGrid code can contain function, which does not exists in Guriddo jqGrid.

Comment: its worknig fine now. Thanks for the help . I have overwriitten the defualts for language file for free jqgrid that was causing problems. But last part i got struck.I want define globally to send some headers in case of add/edit/delete but i have 10 to 20 grids for which i can't define separately. Any idea?

Comment: No idea, but if this is a new problem, please open new issue or write to the support team of Guriddo.

Comment: Thanks for information. its not a bug but i overlooked it. I have 1 more issue.

Comment: I am having a JQGRID displaying filename and lastmodified from a folder in my local system.I am having a delete button too. I have configured jqgrid globally using delete method for DELETE operations but jqgrid is sending POST method for the same. I am  using $.extend(true,$.jgrid.del,{ mtype : 'DELETE'}} .This was working free jqgrid but not in new one . Any idea??? . I am using jquery 3.1

Comment: Guriddo jqGrid  does not support this type of settings. Please see the parameters for delete operations and set the appropriate **mtype**